# I need to update the variant weight and id to get the right shipping estimate on a Shopify product page

Tags: shopify, addeventlistener, event-listener, product-variations

I have created a shipping estimator for the product page of Shopify, the estimator works for the product/variant ID that the page originally loads with, but not when you select a different variant after the page loads, the same is the case of the variants weight.

I want the shipping estimator to get the shipping cost for the individual variants as they are selected.

`This is basically the code I am using in a custom field on a Shopify 2.0 template, I just cant seem to get it to grab the currently selected variant.`

```
          <div>     
          <div id='widgetBespokeProductShippingEstimator' class="quick-actions clearfix">
            {% comment %} Post code and shipping starts here {% endcomment %}
            <label for="txtBespokePostcode" style="font-size:1.3rem;">Estimate Shipping</label>
            <div class="estimate-shipping" style="max-width:44rem;display:flex;">
              <input type="text" id="txtBespokePostcode" class="txtBespokePostcode" maxlength="4" placeholder="Enter postcode" style="border-radius:20px 0px 0px 20px;border:solid 2px;text-align:center;min-width:9.5rem;" />
              <button type="button" id="btnBespokeSubmit" class="button button--full-width btnBespokeSubmit" style="border-radius:0px 20px 20px 0px;--border-offset:0;--border-opacity:0;">Get Estimate</button>
            </div>
            {% comment %} post code and shipping ends here {% endcomment %}
            {% for tag in product.tags %}
              {% if tag == 'free' %}
                <input type="hidden" class="product-tag tag-{{ tag }}" id="product-tag" value="{{ tag }}">{% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            <input type='hidden' id='txtBespokeProductID' value='{{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id}}' />
            <input type='hidden' id='txtBespokeVariantWeight' value='{{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.weight}}' />
            <span id="lblBespokeRate" style="display:block;font-size:1.3rem;max-width:44rem;margin-top:5px;border-radius:20px;box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(34,34,34,0.2);"></span>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!-- BESPOKE SHIPPING - product page shipping estimator -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnBespokeSubmit').on('click',function() {
        var postcode = $(this).siblings('.txtBespokePostcode').val();
        var state = $(this).siblings('.txtBespokeState').val();  
        var id = $('#txtBespokeProductID').val();
        var wt = $('#txtBespokeVariantWeight').val();
        var qty = 1;
        var product_tag = $('#widgetBespokeProductShippingEstimator').first().find('#product-tag').val();
        $('#quantity').each(function() {
            qty = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log({{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id}});  
        console.log({{product.selected_or_first_available_variant.weight}});
        console.log(qty);
        var requestObj = {"origin":{"country":null,"postal_code":null,"province":null,"city":"","name":null,"address1":"","address2":"","address3":null,"phone":"","fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":""},
                            "destination":{"country":"AU","postal_code":postcode,"province":state,"city":"","name":"","address1":"","address2":"","address3":null,"phone":"","fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":""},"items":[
                            {"name":"","sku":"","quantity":qty,"grams":wt,"price":0,"vendor":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"fulfillment_service":"manual","properties":null,"product_id":0,"variant_id":id}
                            ],"currency":"AUD"};
```

Comment: I guess it may required store access to do so, as it seems little complex.